# How can I get rid of annoying y movement and scroll bar on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile

How can I get rid of annoying y movement and scroll bar on mobile devices?

I have a centered box in a div.

The div is set to height: 100vh width: 100vw so that it should take up the whole screen exactly.  That is there should be no scrolling in the x or y direction.

On mobile, there is no scrolling in the x direction as expected however there is scrolling in the y direction on mobile.

PC works as expected.

What is causing this strange effect?  I don't have an easy way to debug mobile so I am having a hard time with it.

Also the box is actually higher up than the center of my mobile device, but is perfectly centered in PC browsers.

Relevant CSS is:

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.page{
  display: flex;    
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}
.box{
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);    
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0px solid #000000; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

and complete fiddle is:

https://jsfiddle.net/ysg8wocn/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would try using @media(maxwidth:___px) {}. just so that users using a certain size screen will have different effects from the same code. I've never worked with mobile but if you haven't already used @media, it's worth a shot.